# Redirect to different ports in Azure cloud service VM (with ARR)

Tags: azure, redirect, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cloud-services, arr

I'm a bit stumped here so I'm hoping someone has some experience with this, the situation is like this:

I have an azure service with a cloud service "mysite.cloudapp.net".
In the service there is a VM "myVM".
In CPanel I have multiple subdomains that redirect to this service which will be named "customer1.site.com", "customer2.site.com" etc. This would be with SSL (wildcard certificate).
Each of these subdomains has to link to a certain port in the VM.

I don't have a problem linking the subdomains to "mysite.cloudapp.net" with DNS in CPanel.

However I'd like that if the url "customer1.site.com" was used that they get forwarded to port 8080/appname.
"customer2.site.com" would instead get forwarded to port 8081/appname. And so on. All these ports have tomcat applications running on them.

I searched around online and it seems ARR would likely be the solution to my problem. Sadly I haven't found a working setup which redirects to the correct ports.

If anyone has experience with a similar situation I would love some input. I'm not used to working with these systems and this setup is a bit more advanced than I expected going in.